# I have to search only duplicate data as shown as bellow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have using sql server 2014.
Data list as i attached image.If there are any duplicates in one after another and it's id's also one after another (running serial) only those are the data that i want to get.
[image: as 2nd image]

[image: 2]

Comment: Please don't post code and data as images. Post code in code fences, and post data in a consumable format; preferably DDL and DML statements, and if not tabular formatted `text`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only compare ID and Doc_Type columns then you can try to do it this way:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Test04 t 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Test04 tp ON t.ID = tp.ID + 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Test04 tn ON t.ID = tn.ID - 1
WHERE 
        (   tp.ID IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (
                SELECT t.Doc_Type
                INTERSECT
                SELECT tp.Doc_Type
            ) )
    OR  (   tn.ID IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS (
                SELECT t.Doc_Type
                INTERSECT
                SELECT tn.Doc_Type
            ) )
```

If more columns needs to be checked then extend the column list in EXISTS subqueries.